# Abelian Groups and Z(G)

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

We know that if we have a group G such that G/Z(G) is **cyclic** this implies that G is **abelian**
Let’s take an example:

If we have |G/Z(G)|=7 which is prime then it is **cyclic** which would imply that G is **abelian**

However, G is **abelian** if and only if G=Z(G)

In the above example we don’t have G=Z(G) since otherwise |G/Z(G)|=1

So does that mean that G/Z(G) can’t be cyclic unless it is the trivial group?

Comment: @Sara the answer to your final question is: Yes.

Comment: I believe this has been asked before. At the very least, I have read the view that it's an awkward situation here in comments. I can't find a duplicate though.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is relatively easy to settle.   While the rug does get pulled out from under you;  you can just say that ok if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic and you assumed it was of order greater than one, you were actually wrong (**reached a contradiction**), so you shouldn't have assumed that the group wasn't abelian.

For instance,  this is how you can prove that a group of order $p^2$ is abelian.   Because if the,  non-trivial,  center has order $p$, you get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

It is precisely for these reasons that I dislike the phrasing. I find the following phrasing better, which accomplishes the same thing:

> If $G$ is a group, $N\leq Z(G)$, and $G/N$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

For your example, I would phrase it as:

> If $G$ is a group, $N\leq Z(G)$, and $G/N$ has order $7$, then $G$ is abelian.

It is indeed true that a less confusing way of phrasing the original would be "If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then it is trivial, and therefore $G$ is abelian." Which is awkward, and why I prefer the phrasing that refers to a quotient modulo a central subgroup, rather than modulo the center.